# error: something wrong with extent

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

- When I try to boot up my system, after selecting Ubuntu* from grub selection screen, the boot process halts quickly:

  ```
  Loading Linux 4.4.0-66-generic ...
  error: something wrong with extent.
  Loading initial ramdisk ...
  alloc magic broken at 0x5eb8f440: 5ea0de60
  Aborted. Press any key to exit.
  ```
- same thing when I select recovery mode.
- When I try to boot with an older kernel version, I get:

  ```
  Loading Linux 4.4.0-63-generic ...
  Loading initial ramdisk ...
  ```

  and then nothing happens.
- with an older Kernel Version it seems the recovery option works

  - repair packages:

    ```
    mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error

    In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try dmesg | trail or so.

    ... (stacktrace info here)
    SystemError: E:Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_xenial-security_InRelease (1), E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
    ```
  - same message without stacktrace when I try fsck

**system/background information:**

I run ubuntu 16.04 with Windows dual boot on my machine.

I think I rebooted the machine after a kernel update or at least some update (that made ubuntu ask me to reboot), but then booted straight into Windows instead.

After trying to boot back to ubuntu, which didn't work, it seems everything was a mess and the root partition had some wrong size, and I was able/forced to do a manual fsck which corrected a lot of stuff.

After that grub was gone completely, so I booted a live ubuntu, fixed the still broken root partition with gparted, installed boot-repair and let that do its magic - which leads me to where I am now.

I'd be grateful for advice